# Architecture Design for API of Cloud Service

Tags: web-services, wcf, asp.net-web-api, cloud, azure-cloud-services

### Background:

I've a local application that process the user input for 3 second (approximately) and then return an answer (output) to the user.

(I don't want to go into details about my application in purpose of not complicate the question and keep it a pure architectural question)

### My Goal:

I want to make my application a service in the cloud and expose API
 (for the upcoming website and for clients that will connect the service without install the software locally)

### Possible Solutions:

1. Deploy WCF on the cloud and use my application there, so clients can invoke the service and use my application on the cloud. **(RPC style)**
2. Use a Web-API that will insert the request into queue and then a worker role will dequeue requests and post the results to a DB, so the client will send one request for creating a request in the queue, and another request for getting the result (which the Web-API will get from the DB).

### The Problems:

- If I go with the WCF solution (#1) I cant handle great loads of requests, maybe 10-20 simultaneously.
- If I go with the WebAPI-Queue-WorkerRole solution (#2) sometimes the client will need to request the results multiple times its can be a problem.
- If I go with the WebAPI-Queue-WorkerRole solution (#2) the process isn't sync, the client will not get the result once the process of his request is done, he need to request the result.

### Questions:

1. In the WebAPI-Queue-WorkerRole solution (#2), can I somehow alert the client once his request has processed and done ? so I can save the client multiple request (for the result).
2. Asking multiple times for the result isn't old stuff ? I remmemeber that 10 - 15 years ago its was accepted but now ? I know that [VirusTotal API](https://www.virustotal.com/he/documentation/public-api/#getting-file-scans)  use this kind of design.
3. There is a better solution ? one that will handle great loads and will be sync or async (returning result to the client once it done) ?

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Azure, why not simply fire up more servers and use load balancing to handle more load?  In that way, as your load increases, you have more servers to handle the requests.

Microsoft recently made available the Azure Service Fabric, which gives you a lot of control over spinning up and shutting down these services.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, go with solution number 1 (WCF, synchronous service) and control it with Azure Service Fabric ?  (for scaling up/down)

Comment: @Ron - Well, you said you wanted a synchronous solution (you don't want your clients to have to poll).  There are other ways to avoid polling as well, but ideally you will get the best results with a service fabric solution.  I don't think Service Fabric uses WCF though.